# CSS: Bottom of dialog box extends beyond bottom of the screen and can't scroll to click buttons

Tags: css, material-ui

I am using material UI to create a dialog box with some text area. However when I put in enough text, the dialog box extends beyond the screen and I can't scroll to the bottom to hit the buttons.

```
<div>
    <TextField hintText="Project Name" floatingLabelText="Pitch Name"/> <div/>
    <TextField hintText="Pitch Name" floatingLabelText="Pitch Name"/> <div/>
    <TextField hintText="Shortcut" floatingLabelText="Shortcut"/> <div/>
    <TextField hintText="Subject" floatingLabelText="Subject"/> <div/>
    <TextField 
        fullWidth='true' 
        multiLine="true" 
        hintText="Pitch" 
        floatingLabelText="Pitch"
    /> <div/>
</div>
```

I start with this:

[image]

If I put in enough text, I get this:

[image]

When the dialog extends beyond the bottom of the page I can't scroll to the buttons. Is there some setting I need to put in to allow me to?

Any idea on how to handle this?

Comment: You probably just need to put an `overflow: auto` property dialog to allow scrolling if content exceeds the view

Comment: do I add overflow to to the parent or the child? or to the page in general?

Comment: The parent that contains all the TextFields

Comment: Yup! that worked! exactly what I was looking for. thank you. if you put this as a formal answer I'll mark it as right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you put an `overflow: auto` property on the parent container it should allow you to scroll only when the content exceeds the view